# Clean array if the condtion is false

Tags: php

For example

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res))
{
    if($row == 2)
        $statment[] = $row->name;
    else
        $statment[] = ''; 
}
```

When i do `print_r($statment)`, it also includes empty records in it.

Comment: Are you really comparing an object against a value of 2? Surely you should be comparing a property of that object, rather than the whole object itself

Answer (score 2):

Don't add the '' to the statement then.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
   if($row == 2)
      $statment[] = $row->name;
}
```

Comment: This is the actual solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for this after the end of your while statement.

```
$nonemptyarray = array_filter($yourarray, 'strlen');
```

### The code..

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res))
{
    if($row == 2)
        $statment[] = $row->name;
    else
        $statment[] = ''; 
}
$nonemptyarray = array_filter($statment, 'strlen');
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm almost there - what if results are ( array[0]='', array[1]='', array[2]=67 )
I just want to show record 67 but i don't know the position of array where exactly 67 is. i hope you got my point.
result should be array[0]=>67 always. so that i can - echo $record[0] and output 67

Comment: If your `67` is in the second index of your array, why can't you just `echo $yourarray[2];` ?

Comment: what if 67 is on 3rd index? this could be change as per the result.

Comment: Make use of `echo $position=array_search(67,$yourarray);` returns you the position where `67` is.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `$statment = '';` with `$statment = array();`

Answer (score 0):

In your else statement just replace `$statment[] = '';` with `$statment = array();`